# EPSG Geodetic Parameter Registry - SW supporting transformation EPSGs

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, coordinates, software-recommendations, epsg

The page [www.epsg-registry.org](http://www.epsg-registry.org) contains EPSG codes for different transformations (i.e. EPSG:1173, EPSG:1244 etc.).

Do you know about some GIS SW (online or desktop), which supports converting coordinates using these transformations?

Comment: Blue Marble's Geographic Calculator (and their other software), Esri's ArcGIS software (but we don't expose the IDs). PROJ4 and software built on it (GDAL, QGIS) will often hard-code a transformation into the +TOWGS84 parameter.

Comment: I believe that with the pipelines https://proj4.org/operations/pipeline.html# which are new to Proj4 5.0 you can build your own tailored transformation chains.